# Magical System.out.println("prompt"); wont display output

Tags: java, println

The code shown below is my main method of a maze game I am creating.
In this main method I have a while loop that goes on until the game is finished.
In the while loop I print the maze then ask the user which direction they want to move their character.
I am having a crazy problem, the prompt to the user asking for the key, wont display. 
The output just prints the maze and then waits for user input.

```
        do
        {               
            maze.printArray();              
            //Asks the user which direction they wish to move THIS LINE NEVER SHOWS UP!
            System.out.print ("Enter U,L,D,R to indicate move direction:   ");              
            //Gets the string from user, and changes it to a char, then converts it to an uppercase 
            direction = read.next().charAt(0);
            direction = Character.toUpperCase(direction);                   
            //Moves the character and increments the invalidMoves counter if the move was not legal
            if(maze.move(direction) == false)
                invalidMoves++;                 
            //Increment the move count regardless of its validity
            moves++;
        }
        while(maze.isFinished() == false);
```

This is the printArray method which is called before the print.

```
public void printArray() 
{
    for (char [] x : mazeArray) 
    {
        for (char y : x) 
        {
            //Print the characters for the row
            System.out.print (y);
        }           
        //linebreak to go to next row
        System.out.println ();
    }
    System.out.println ();
}
```

The 2D array holds a maze pattern which is displayed to the screen as such

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XO-------X
XX-XXX-XXX
XX---X---X
XXXX-X-X-X
X----X-XXX
X-XXXX--$X
XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Instead of `someCondition == false`, you might want to consider `!someCondition`.

Comment: Don't to scared to post some code here. We will not trying to steal your idea. We can't see and find your source of problem, except you post what result that you got after `DEBUGGING` it and what line from the code that make the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `println` instead of `print`...

Comment: @NullPointerException: In that case, you will need to provide a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: um, im not sure what you want me to include.
will the maze.printArray(); method help?

Comment: @NullPointerException: Just the shortest possible code that compiles on its own and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added some stuff. tell me if more things are required

Comment: @NullPointerException: What I'm interested in is to be able to recreate the problem myself.  I can't do that unless you post a **complete** program; but that program should be as short as possible.  So strip out all the irrelevant stuff (get rid of absolutely everything you can), and then post a **complete** program.

Comment: I dont think i can, there's too much necessary code to post here

Comment: @NullPointerException: What Oli means is you post some example program based on your problem. Because we didn't understand yet what you mean here. For example I didn't understand what kind of object `read` that you used here. If you don't mind please create one `Main` class that describe your problem. So that we can copy-paste to our local and try to help find your problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.
I didn't have time that day to create an example.
I ended up completely avoiding the output and placing it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try `System.out.flush();` after the `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your code has called System.setOut(printStream), you can restore it to stdout with:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
```

If stdout was redirected somewhere when the process was called, you can specify your own PrintStream with:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt")));
```

Or you can just write to the PrintStream directly:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));
ps.println("hi");
```